# Thread and Runnable object differences

Tags: java, multithreading

I couldn't find a question similar enough to this, but I do apologize if this is a duplicate.

```
//do something

//start

new Thread(r).start();

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                //do something
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
    };//end new Runnable
```

My question is: Am I using a thread? or just a runnable object? Not sure if I am even asking a meaningful question?

I am new to threads, but my understanding of this code is : I am starting a new thread, passing it a runnable object, and it begins the overridden run method, in this case the thread will sleep for 5 seconds then do work.

Comment: The concept of Threads always is confusing. But yes anything run inside run() will be a separate Thread.

Comment: Lets say "new Thread(r).start();" is inside a loop. Each time this statement executes does a new Thread begin or does the current Thread become the new one?

Comment: you say new every time. So as long you keep using word new in your code then yes new thread is created in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're using a Thread.
You create it by passing to its constructor a Runnable object.

"I am starting a new thread, passing it a runnable object, and it begins the overridden run method, in this case the thread will sleep for 5 seconds then do work."

This is correct, but the key point is missing: that this run method will be executed in another/new Thread, and not in the Thread from which you called start() on the Thread object which you created.

Answer (score 2):

The `Runnable` interface just declares the fact that the class that implements it is able to be executed in a thread, so that it provides the interface to be called and executed by an external thread, nothing more.

A `Thread` implements `Runnable` since it's able to execute its own `run()` method but Runnable in general doesn't have anything related to threading itself. The default run() of Thread doesn't do anything, that's why you usually extend it and define the specific behavior of your thread.

But just to clarify, a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) accepts `Runnable` objects exactly like a `Thread`. It's just the interface which declares that the class definition, is indeed, runnable (or executable).

Answer (score 2):

1. You created a new anonymous implementation of `Runnable` interface.
2. This implementation povided the action to perform when executing the this implementation in a new `Thread`
3. You created a new `Thread` (`new Thread(r)`) and passed the anonymous instance to thread instance
4. When you started executing the thread (`new Thread(r).start()`), the jvm created a new thread. This new thread in turn invoked the run() method of the anonymous `Runnable` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of `Thread` (as you create in the first line of code) represents a physical thread. When you call `start()`, the JVM will spawn a new thread (using the OS native methods to do so) and start its execution.

A `Runnable` is just an interface that defines the `run()` method (as you do in your second line of code). If you pass any object implementing `Runnable` to the `Thread` constructor, then the thread will run the code defined in the `run()` method.

`Runnable`s are very lightweight since they only define one method, while `Thread`s come with the heavy weight of a physical thread.

Directly creating a `Thread` is not recommended since it's an expensive operation. I highly recommend you look at the [java Executors framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) as it provides a flexible way of creating thread pools and submitting tasks (in the form of `Runnable`s or `Callable`s) to them. The Executors framework provides invaluable facilities for thread reuse.